# Using the .Condition option in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, automapper

Can anyone tell me the proper VB.NET syntax to accomplish the following:

```
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Value != "removeMe"))
```

This is the best I've got, but I get a design-time error on the last statement that reads "property access must assign to the property or use it's value"

```
.ForAllMembers(Function(opt) opt.Condition(Sub(src As OrganizationMetric) src.Value <> "removeMe"))
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

This is the final code that works, had to switch around my Function() and Sub():

```
.ForAllMembers(Sub(opt) opt.Condition(Function(src As OrganizationMetric) src.Value <> "removeMe"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.ForAllMembers(Function(opt) opt.Condition(Function(src) src.Value <> "removeMe"))
```

Comment: The expression "opt.Condition(...)" in this case produces an error "Expression does not produce a value".  It also doesn't recognize src as the proper type in IntelliSense.

Comment: Condition() takes a parameter of type 'System.Func', not 'System.Action' which I why I chose Sub over Function.

Comment: @Ben for System.Func you should use Function nor Sub. Is it `System.Func(Of OrganizationMetric, Boolean)` ?

Comment: Ok, but it still produces the error I mentioned above: "Expression does not produce a value".  Yes, that is the second signature.  The first signature is `System.Func(Of Automapper.ResolutionContext, Boolean)` which is why I declared the type in my code.

Comment: Can you post what the signature of `ForAllMembers()` and `Condition()`  ?

Comment: I've found it.  The "Expression does not produce a value" error was because of my use of Function(opt) instead of Sub(opt).  Thanks for the help!